# Why does my code duplicate the css of a file?

Tags: sass, node-sass

In Sass I have some components (navbar, footer) and some `@mixins` (fonts) and a function to control the fonts.

I `@import` the location of the fonts and do `@include` in the function of the fonts, in this function I just choose the font I want to use.

The problem is that as I separated as "partials" the components (navbar and footer) they have the same sources and I gave `@import` in those sources in each *.scss*.

And with that it generates duplicate code in my generated *.scss* file. I'd like to know what good practices are for this and if I'm doing it right and how do I avoid these duplicates in *.scss*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't see your code, I am not sure how you imported your resources exactly. However, if you are only generating one `.css` file, a good practice is to import everything on the file that will be compiled and not on each partial.

Let's imagine you have the following structure :

```
styles
├─ components
│   ├─ _footer.scss
│   └─ _navbar.scss
├─ settings
│   ├─ _functions.scss
│   └─ _mixins.scss
└─ styles.scss
```

In this example, `styles.sccs` is the only one that will be compiled, it will be used only to import all partials (the order matters):

```
// Settings

@import './settings/mixins';
@import './settings/functions';

// Components

@import './components/footer';
@import './components/navbar';
```

You then can use any mixins or functions in your components and everything is only imported once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question – but to prevent duplicates in Sass I would create a mixin to check if an `@include` has already been made

**SCSS**

```
//  Global list to keep track of what mixins has been included 
$include-once: (); 

//  Mixin helper to be used inside other mixins we would like 
//  not to produce duplicate content
@mixin once($mixin-name) {
   //  check if mixin name exists in our list 
   @if not index($include-once, $mixin-name) {

       //  add mixin name to list (using the global flag)
       $include-once: append($include-once, $mixin-name) !global;

       //  print out the content of the mixin
       @content;
   } 
}



//  Use example
@mixin font {
    //  wrap content in the include once wrapper passing the name of the mixin 
    @include once(font){

        //  make sure font import is not nested 
        @at-root {
            @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
        }
    }
}


//  Test
.foo { @include font; color: red; }
.bar { @include font; color: green; }
.baz { @include font; color: blue; }
```

**CSS Output**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans")
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.bar {
  color: green;
}

.baz {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of late to the game, but I experienced this issue and having partials or using @include did not work. What did it for me was using i.e. css-nano-webpack-plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssnano-webpack-plugin. I'm using webpack v5, so could not get it to work using the webpack mini-css-extract-plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin.

Please bear in mind that the below snippet minimizes and minifies the css PER scss file. So, repetitions between files may still make it in the .css output file.

So, include it in your webpack config like so (source is the npmjs cssnano-webpack-plugin site)

```
const CssnanoPlugin = require('cssnano-webpack-plugin');
 
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.s?css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new CssnanoPlugin()
    ]
  }
};
´´´
```